# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01-02-2014"

Tags: java, date

I am newbie with servlet and jsp. I am trying to insert date into table with more information. This is my code

```html
 
try{
 DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date reg=sdf.parse(request.getParameter("dob")); 
 }
catch(ParseException e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

When I am debugging and control reaches to this line it throws an error saying

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01-02-2014"

can any body help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is dd/MM/yyyy but date is 01-02-2014.
Make date format matching expected input. Like this:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: I am really sorry but could make it more clear Plz. as I can see i am giving the same format